# Device not tested during pre-launch Android

Tags: android, testing, google-play-console, prelaunch

I've just uploaded an APK for an alpha release of my app (my first app). In the pre-launch report I received a message that a device wasn't tested. (Galaxy J7). I've reviewed the specs of the phone and I can't see any reason why my app wouldn't work on it. Is this normal?

[image]

I'd also note that pre-launch didn't flag this device as having an issue. No devices had an issue, it just specified that it didn't test this device.

Specifying a specific device it didn't test just seems a bit odd to me unless there was an issue. An analogy for my confusion is like taking your car to a mechanic to get your oil changed and the mechanic says "oil is changed, but I didn't look at your tires". By specifying he didn't do something makes me wonder if I should be looking into them.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it can't be tested, it doesn't mean there's device incompatibility. It's basically the free version of something firebase offers paid, you have to expect it to not test all devices sometimes because of high load

Comment: @LunarWatcher, gotcha so during prelaunch, it 'tried' to test the app on the device but couldn't get access to the device so the device was skipped over?

Comment: Most likely. I'm not fully familiar with the system, but it seems like the most reasonable thing that happens. If there's no device incompatibility, and since you're using the free version, you are probably deprioritized compared to those who use the paid version

Comment: If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct. I found a typo, and did an update, the second time, pre-launch ran the device with no issues. I feel fairly confident the device was skipped the first time for the reasons you've mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that that the device wasn't available. As you run the free version of something Firebase offers to paid customers, the free version isn't prioritized. It isn't device incompatibility that is the issue, it's more likely that there was no device available to handle the test at the time.